# Что лучше: брать по несколько байтов recv() TCP ( по 2 или 4 байта ) или брать сразу все данные?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, tcp, сокеты, сетевое-программирование

Например, я каждый раз вызываю функцию recv() и принимаю по 2 байта или 4 байта, в зависимости от необходимости , обрабатыаю полученые байты и снова вызываю recv для получения других 2 байтов и так далее. Или же сразу всё целиком получить в буфер , например 512 байтов, и обрабатывать данные по этому буферу. Вопрос в производительности. Как работает recv на програмном уровне.

Answer (score 2):

В большинстве случаев, recv - это системный вызов, который приводит к переходу в ядро, где с очереди берется хотя бы один байт. Если нет - вызов может ждать данные.

Переход в режим ядра часто стоит очень дорого. Поэтому, лучше забирать по максимуму и потом обрабатывать у себя.

А можно использовать различные библиотеки, которые сами будут буферизировать данные.